# Why is the Japanese term for grammatical case 「格」? How did this translation come to be?

Tags: etymology, terminology, linguistics

From Google's definition of 格:

> 1. きまり。法則。標準。
>       「格式・格言・合格・別格・破格・規格・本格・古格・適格・律令格式(りつりょうきゃくしき)」
> 2. 《名・造》地位。身分。程度。
>       「格が違う」
> 3. 方形に組みあわせた材。
>       「骨格・格子(こうし)・格天井(ごうてんじょう)」
> 4. くる。いたる。とおる。きわめる。
>       「格物致知」
> 5. ただす。ただしい。
>       「厳格」
> 6. 《名・造》文法上、文中で語句が他の語句に対する意味的関係。
>       「格がかわる」
> 7. 《名》論理学上、三段論法の形式。
> 8. 手でうつ。うつ。「挌(かく)」に同じ。
>       「格闘・格技」

Definition #2 appears to be the closest in meaning to the grammatical usage #6. I am curious: When was this term first translated? And whom should the credit go to for coining it? How did a word denoting social status--namely something on a linear high/low spectrum--come to refer to grammatical categorization of nouns, pronouns, and other words?

Comment: 中国語でも同じ使われ方をしているようなので、そっち由来かも…。

Comment: Then aren't there fair odds that the Chinese borrowed it from the Japanese, like a lot of modern linguistic (or more broadly, academic) terms?

Comment: 僕は後者に10ペリカですね（笑）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not answer your question of how 格 came to be used, but only (roughly) when and by whom. In short, the term comes from translations of Dutch grammar in late 18th centruy.

From [this article](https://www.chs.nihon-u.ac.jp/wpchs/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/2020%E3%80%80%E6%95%99%E5%B8%AB%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E3%81%A8%E5%AE%9F%E8%B7%B5%E7%9F%A5%E3%80%80%E7%AC%AC5%E5%B7%BB%E3%80%803.pdf)

> 日本人が格変化と出会ったのは実はドイツ語が
> 初めてではない。鎖国時代も貿易を続けたオラン
> ダの言語オランダ語も文語では格変化を形式的で
> はあるが維持していた。よって江戸時代の蘭学者
> たちも格変化の情報を知っていた筈である。彼ら
> の文法用語はどうなっているかといえば，蘭語学
> で最も功績のある中野柳圃『三種諸格』（1781
> 年）における格の表記は以下の通りである。

> 中野はこの本の種本として Wilhelm Sewel „Nederduytsche Spraakkonst“ というオランダ語の文法書を使っているが，この原書には番号をつけた
> 格表記はない。中野は主や生といった格の名称の
> 横に番号を記している。ただし文法説明にこの番
> 号を用いて 1 格というような表現はしていない。

[Another article](https://www.jacp.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1996_23_hikaku_09_hatanaka.pdf) cites 和蘭語法解 by 藤林普山 (1815) as the source of translation. The following article cited in this may answer your question fully, but I don't have access to it.

- [「格」という文法用語について--その由来と現状](https://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R000000004-I1863944-00?ar=4e1f)

==

Also 角川古語大辞典's entry of 格 says its meaning as a grammatical term comes from 蘭文典の研究.